# ReactJS Adding Edit Feature to SchoolFinder

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'm new to ReactJS, but by following the tutorials I was able to build a SchoolFinder app as explained in the link below. Now I'm trying to add a edit feature to it.

Link to tutorial [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1067725/Part-Building-web-app-using-react-js-express-js).

So I've added `<AddSchool onEdit={this.updateSchool}/>`
and

```
updateSchool: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  actions.updateSchool(this.props.info);
}
```

In SchoolList.jsx and in Actions i've written the updateSchool function, but it is not getting called. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please, share `AddSchool` to see how `onEdit` props is used there

Comment: I haven't used it yet, how do i pass on the data to addSchool from SchoolStore, can I set onEdit props in SchoolStore?

Comment: Exactly as you did: `<AddSchool onEdit={this.updateSchool}/>`. But you say that `updateSchool` is not called. The question is: how `AddSchool` is using `onEdit`. You should see `onEdit` in `AddSchool` code. I suggest you to follow [React tuto](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) to understand how React works